# Issue with Python packages on BigSur beta but only from the shell

Tags: macos, terminal, python, big-sur

Since I am running the BigSur beta, I can't use Qt from python anymore; the viewer opens and closes instantly.

I have this in the console:

```
Sandbox: logd_helper(207) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.abi3.so
```

running python as root doesn't make an difference

but even numpy has a problem:

```
Sandbox: logd_helper(207) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/.dylibs/libgcc_s.1.dylib
```

this problem may be related to this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587131/macos-big-sur-python-ctypes-find-library-does-not-find-libraries-ssl-corefou

What is weird is that if I run the script from the IDE PyCharm, everything runs well, but not from the shell. How comes is this happening?

Comment: What python are you using in the shell and what one is pycharm using?

Comment: they're both the same; since I wasn't sure, I decided to 'un-pythonize' my machine, just leaving the default Apple ones (/usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python3) and re-install with brew (/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3)